# Why do developers set 'this' to a variable (e.g. 'self' or 'that')?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, oop

When I inherit another developers code base I will often see something declaration like the following:
I have seen this most frequently used in LWCs. But I'm not sure what the purpose is and given the generic nature of the terms `this`, `that`, and `self`, standard google searching has not helped.

```
let self = this; 

//

let that = this;
```

What is the point of doing this? Is it merely to keep track of the 'this' object in a different context? Does this impact how `this` functions once it is assigned to `self` or `that`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is a fickle creature when you're talking about normal functions in JavaScript, because it changes based on context. For example:

```
let value = {
    src: "hello",
    output: function() {
        console.log(this.src);
    }
};
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.onerror = value.output;
img.src = "hello world";
```

You might be tempted to think that the console.log would output "hello", but it'll actually output whatever img.src resolves to.

We fix this by preserving this:

```
let value = {
    src: "hello",
    output: function() {
        let self = this;
        return function() {
            console.log(self.src);
        }
    }
};
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.onerror = value.output();
img.src = "hello world";
```

This happens completely by "accident" in Aura, for example, by using $A.getCallback, which sets `this` to `$A` and not your component.

This often becomes a problem when you do something like:

```
setTimeout($A.getCallback(
    function() {
        this.callOtherHelperMethod();
    }
));
```

Here, we want to make an asynchronous call to another helper method, but we'll be disappointed with an error.

There's a few ways to fix this, the "easiest" is to just bind this to a variable:

```
let self = this;
setTimeout($A.getCallback(
    function() {
        self.callOtherHelperMethod();
    }
));
```

This works because it creates a "closure." In other words, the function will remember the reference to `this` as it was assigned to `self` earlier.

That's not the only way to this, though. We can preserve `this` with `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
setTimeout($A.getCallback(
    function() {
        this.callOtherHelperMethod();
    }.bind(this)
));
```

Now, `this` is properly bound to its context without the need for a closure variable.

Or, we can use arrow functions:

```
setTimeout($A.getCallback(
    () => {
        this.callOtherHelperMethod();
    }
));
```

Arrow functions **always** remember the `this` they were defined in, regardless of where they are called or otherwise assigned to. In other words, you always know where `this` is.

Edit: I just realized that this was asked in context of LWCs, and the answer there is "you should not need closures to remember `this` in LWCs"; most developers in our ecosystem tend to be novices and/or used to Aura. My LWC experience is limited, but I've never had to use a closure to remember the object I'm working on. I just use arrow functions, which resolves the ambiguity quite nicely, and is less code, too.

Comment: This helps a lot, and still helps even with your edit. Just clarifying here, but you're essentially saying that we use the `self` or `that` variables to (which could be `x` the name doesn't really matter) preserve the `variable-scope` and/or context of `this`. Am I correct in my understanding of what you've posted? It also seems like Arrow functions were designed to handle context of `this` and are not just for making code look better. :D

Comment: @thinker Yes, we're putting `this` in a *closure* to preserve the original context of the function, that's the only reason why you'd do this. And yes, arrow functions are the logical replacement to the "OG" JavaScript methods that we had to use in ancient s-controls, Visualforce, and even naively written Aura. Every browser supported by Lightning supports Arrow functions, so there's no reason not to use them when appropriate (notably, don't use them if you actually want `this` to reference an object, typically `FileReader`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc).